# Endless Recyclerview not Working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a recyclerview which loads 500 items, That is why i am paginating it so that 500+ items list don't load at once.

My Adapter:

```
public class MenuListsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuListsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

// Store a member variable for the contacts
private List<MenuList> menuList;

// Pass in the contact array into the constructor
public MenuListsAdapter(List<MenuList> contacts) {
    menuList = contacts;
}

// Provide a direct reference to each of the views within a data item
// Used to cache the views within the item layout for fast access
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // Your holder should contain a member variable
    // for any view that will be set as you render a row
    public TextView txtDesc;

    // We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row
    // and does the view lookups to find each subview
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
        // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
        super(itemView);

        txtDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menulistview_layout, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    MenuList contact = menuList.get(position);

    TextView textView = viewHolder.txtDesc;
    textView.setText(contact.getTxtDesc());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return menuList.size();
}
}
```

My EndlessRecyclerScrollListener:

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
// The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
// before loading more.
private int visibleThreshold = 8;
// The current offset index of data you have loaded
private int currentPage = 0;
// The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
// True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private boolean loading = true;
// Sets the starting page index
private int startingPageIndex = 0;

RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
    this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
}

public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(GridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
    this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
    visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
}

public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
    this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
    visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
}

public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
    int maxSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
        }
        else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
            maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
        }
    }
    return maxSize;
}

// This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
// We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
// but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {
    int lastVisibleItemPosition = 0;
    int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

    if (mLayoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
        int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
        // get maximum element within the list
        lastVisibleItemPosition = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
    } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
        lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
        lastVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
    // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
    if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        if (totalItemCount == 0) {
            this.loading = true;
        }
    }
    // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
    // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
    // number and total item count.
    if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
        loading = false;
        previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
    }

    // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
    // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
    // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
    // threshold should reflect how many total columns there are too
    if (!loading && (lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount) {
        currentPage++;
        onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount);
        loading = true;
    }
}

// Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

}
```

My Fragment Where RecyclerView is generated inside OnCreateView Method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
    //genDummyItems();

    menuRV = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.menuRV);
    final List<MenuList> allContacts = MenuList.createMenuList(100, 0);
    adapter = new MenuListsAdapter(allContacts);
    menuRV.setAdapter(adapter);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    menuRV.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    menuRV.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            List<MenuList> moreContacts = MenuList.createMenuList(10, 0);
            int curSize = adapter.getItemCount();
            allContacts.addAll(moreContacts);
            adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(curSize, allContacts.size() - 1);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Recycler View is flickering onScroll, Kindly guide what i am missing so i can make endless recycler properly.

Comment: `RecyclerView` itself is intelligent enough to not load more item than visible on screen. Remove the `onScrollListener` in the `onCreateView` and it should work fine. In the `onScroll` method of `EndlessRecyclerScrollListener`, you are essentially doing the work of `onBindViewHolder` of the `Adapter`. You don't need `EndlessRecyclerScrollListener` class.

Comment: By default if i attach list with recyclerview it shows all items in recyclerview, but i dont want this. I want recyclerview to show item like 10 than another 10 so on....

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: what is your criteria for showing list items?? Does it depend on scrolling? `RecyclerView` load only that content which is visible on screen. Any view which is not visible on screen is not loaded by `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Yes you are right but my scenario is different. My recyclerview is loading 500 items at once and it is making my app slow. So i want recyclerview to load 10 items at first and when user approach to bottom via scrolling it loads next 10. But its not working

Comment: Can anyone give me a simple example of Endless recyclerview in fragment....

Comment: How do you know it is loading 500 items at once?

Comment: Because i m passing array list to adapter which contains 500 items

Comment: final List<MenuList> allContacts = MenuList.createMenuList(100, 0); //Passing 100 items at start

Comment: Kindly see above code, shared all my code related to recyclerview

Comment: You seriously need to have a look at how `ListView` or `RecyclerView` works internally. There are many tutorials like [this](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156) or [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html), also you must watch video titled ["world of list view"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) from google I/O 2010. Search for it on YouTube.

Comment: Even though you are passing all the data to adapter at once, it doesn't cause any problem.

Comment: Do you know about Pagination????????? Why its use.......

Comment: I want to develop exaclty this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqJAKA5IEF8

Comment: no body knows how to do it??????????????????????????